# jTDS ssl connection hangs with JRE 1.8

Tags: java, ssl, jdbc, sql-server-2008-r2, jtds

I am using jTDS to make ssl connection to SQL Server 2008 database in my java application which is running on JRE 1.8.

When I configure ssl=request property in connection URL the connection just hangs in JRE 1.8. However the same thing works perfectly fine in JRE 1.7.

I tried doing same thing using Microsoft jdbc driver with encrypt=true property and it works perfectly fine in both JRE 1.7 and 1.8.

Any idea why this must be happening?

I am not able to understand whether this is a bug with jTDS or Java 8 or SQL Server 2008.

Comment: I have also a problem with SSL in java 8 (http invoker in spring), while it is fine in java 7

Comment: Which version of jTDS are you using?

Comment: The latest one: 1.3.1

Answer (score 4):

There is a bug in the TdsTlsOutputStream implementation. I've posted a patch for a jtds-1.3.1.

See: https://sourceforge.net/p/jtds/bugs/725

Comment: The latest one: 1.3.1

Comment: @TechnoCrat, any idea when the official release would be made. Is the project staled ? No one seems to be responding on the site

Comment: @NidaSahar Project looks like staled. There are many comments about this bug on the jTDS bug list. No comment from the owner. I suggest you to compile patched version of the jTDS by yourself. We have been are running it in the production successfully for two releases already.